# Can't find MPI and Can't find GDAL when traudem::taudem_sitrep()

Tags: gdal, r, taudem

i'm trying to intsall `traudem` in R to use `rivnet` package and i've followed the intructions to intsall TauDEM, GDAL and MPI on windows using the complete installer provided (https://github.com/dtarb/TauDEM/releases/download/v5.3.7/TauDEM537_setup.exe) but once i try to verify the installation the following errors appear:

```
> traudem::taudem_sitrep()
Error in `traudem::taudem_sitrep()`:
! ✖ Can't find MPI
ℹ Please install MPI. See vignette('taudem-installation').
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
✖ Can't find GDAL via gdal-config nor gdalinfo.
ℹ Are you sure you installed GDAL? See vignette('taudem-installation').
```

i have checked and both MPI and GDAL are correctly intsalled but there is no further information on how fix this errors or how to properly link R to MPI and GDAL for the `traudem` package to work.